# Definite integral over an infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, infinite-product

> Evaluate the following integral $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x+1}{x+2}\cdot\frac{x+3}{x+4}\cdot\frac{x+5}{x+6}\cdots dx$$

When I saw this, I was pretty sure that the infinite term must telescope or it must be a standard Progression or anything like that. But when I sat down to solve it, no simplifications were appearing. I also tried to isolate the $x+1$ and laboured to form a pattern but in vain. I wonder how to solve it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The integrand has a  [Pochhammer symbol](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Pochhammer%28%281+%2B+x%29%2F2%2C+m%29%2FPochhammer%28%282+%2B+x%29%2F2%2C+m%29%2Cm%3D4) closed form. When there are infinite factors, the integrand [is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5BPochhammer%28%281+%2B+x%29%2F2%2C+m%29%2FPochhammer%28%282+%2B+x%29%2F2%2C+m%29%2Cm-%3Einfinity%5D) $0$.

Comment: How to do it by hand?

Comment: I have doubts this integral converges

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have
$$
\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x+(2k-1)}{x+2k}
=\prod_{k=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac{1}{x+2k}\right)=0
$$
since for $0\le x\le 1$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x+2k}\ge \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+2k}=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k}= 2\left(\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\dots\right) =\infty.
$$
So the answer is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

For each $x$, the integrand is a product of number strictly smaller than $1$ (and positive).

The integrand noted

$$f(x) := \prod_n u_n $$

Is a product of term strictly increasing and strictly smaller than $1$.

$$u_0(x) < u_n(x) <1, ~\forall n, x. $$

Then
$$f(x) \leq \prod_i u_0(x), \forall x. $$

And this product is $0$ on real numbers since $u_0<1$.

Comment: This reasoning is not rigorous, because the product $$\prod_{k=2}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{k^2}\right) = \prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k-1}{k} \frac{k+1}{k} = \frac{1}{2},$$ yet the sequence $$u_k = 1 - \frac{1}{k^2}$$ for $k \ge 2$ satisfies all of your criteria (with an inconsequential change in starting index numbering).

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks ! Do you  know a criteria to make an infinite product of element smaller than 1 converges ? (maybe with log function and sum criteria)